# SSRS Subscription - Error Sending Report via Email

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm receiving an error on a report subscription. The error is below.
I've never seen this error before. Is this related to the size of the Excel file that's being attached to the email?

```
runningjobs!WindowsService_0!1004!01/15/2020-23:58:50:: i INFO: Adding: 1 running jobs to the database
library!WindowsService_0!70c!01/15/2020-23:59:08:: i INFO: Initializing EnableExecutionLogging to 'True'  as specified in Server system properties.
emailextension!WindowsService_0!70c!01/15/2020-23:59:13:: e ERROR: Error sending email. Exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Error reading data, max message size exceeded
   at System.Net.Mail.DataStopCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String serverResponse)
   at System.Net.Mail.DataStopCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn)
   at System.Net.ClosableStream.Close()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.EmailDeliveryProvider.EmailProvider.Deliver(Notification notification)
notification!WindowsService_0!70c!01/15/2020-23:59:13:: e ERROR: Error occurred processing subscription 89629c0b-81ec-4ecd-b347-d247b7d2d3c4: Failure sending mail: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Error reading data, max message size exceeded
```

Comment: I tried sending to my GMAIL but it is still failing. Is there a way to check the file size or only by running it manually and checking?

Comment: Run it manually and check, keeping in mind it will grow a bit when encoded to add to an email.